# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting error message: Invalid argument for foreach() in my View. I wanted to display all entries in my mysql table but i kept on getting error message. I am a newbie in Codeigniter and couldn't really figure out how to solve this. The codes are the following:
My model (display_branch.php)

```
<?php if(!defined ('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Display_Branch extends CI_Model
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function getAll()
{
    $this->db->select('bcode, bname, btel, badd');
    $this->db->from('branches');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $results = $query->result();
        return $results;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}?>
```

My Controller (link_controller.php) *only the snippet.

```
public function insert()
{
    $this->load->model('display_branch');

    $data['results'] = $this->display_branch->getAll(); 

    $this->load->view('insert_branch');
    $this->load->view('navigation');
    $this->load->view('content_bc', $data);
    $this->load->view('footers');
}
```

And my view(content_bc.php)

```
<?php


        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->bcode.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->bname.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->btel.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->badd.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

?>
```

Please help me what to do. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked `var_dump($results)`, what did it output?

Comment: Your $results array is empty. How many rows does your branches table have? At the moment you are returning an empty array unless the table only has a single result.

Comment: Your code is good, it is something with the table

Comment: another alternative is to check whether you got results in the model or the controller - and then call the appropriate view. it can make your views easier to work with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to do a check before starting to iterate for the data, like:
model code:

```
public function getAll() {
    $results = array();
    $this->db->select('bcode, bname, btel, badd');
    $this->db->from('branches');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return $results;
}
```

view code:

```
if( !empty($results) ) {
    foreach($results as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->bcode.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->bname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->btel.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->badd.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @DemoUser I used the same code. Now, error is not coming..        but, data is also not displaying. when i echo var_dump($results).. its coming NULL.? So, any idea.? What to do. ?

Comment: @DanishEnam that would mean your query returned empty result, that is your query didnot match any records... try running the query in phpmyadmin to confirm its returning records..

Answer (score 1):

The query in your model is returning either string or object data, instead of an array. The 'foreach' loop function accepts an array as its first argument.

Comment: saved lot of my time - in my situation it was JSON string and missed decoding the result.

Comment: Glad i could help. For safety you should check if it's an array is_array($array)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code modular:

```php
public function getAll() {
    $this->db->select('bcode, bname, btel, badd');
    $this->db->from('branches');

    $query = $this->db->get('branches');

    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```