# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in codeigniter model

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

```
function mostViewedTracks() {
    $this->load->database();        
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("file");
    $this->db->order_by("views", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(8);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return array();
}
```

when i run this model it gives error that invalid argument supplied for foreach()

this is my view code:

```
    <?php if( !empty($most_viewed) ) { ?>
    <?php foreach($most_viewed as $row): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/home/track');?>/<?php echo $row->id;?>" class="list-group-item">
    <img class="track-list-img" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/music');?>/<?php echo $row->id;?>.jpg">
    <div class="list-track-infoo">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $row->title;?><span class="badge"><?php echo $row->views;?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></span> </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php echo $row->singer;?></p>
    </div>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php} ?>
```

**Updated**

Controller

```
function track() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data1['track'] = $this->view_models->track($id);
    $data1['most_viewed'] = $this->view_models->mostViewedTracks();
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('track', $data1);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

I have tried my best to solve this problem but all in vain

Comment: provide proper code

Comment: please check again I have updated my question

Comment: your returning array  use return $results; in model

Comment: instead of `return array();` use `return $query->result();`

Comment: what is the value of $most_viewed?

Comment: Same problem after using return $query->result(); too

Comment: Post your controller code too!!

Comment: value of $most_viewed is integer value

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951168/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-codeigniter

Comment: public function track()
 { 
  $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  
  $data1['track'] = $this->view_models->track($id);
  $data1['most_viewed'] = $this->view_models->mostViewedTracks();
  
  $this->load->view('includes/header');
  $this->load->view('track', $data1);
  $this->load->view('includes/footer');
 }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return array();` you have to return result set from models file

```
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
         return $query->result();// return result set 
    }else{
          return FALSE;//
    }
```

IN controller you have to call your models function as

```
$data1['most_viewed'] = $this->view_models->getFeaturedTracks();// change mostViewedTracks to getFeaturedTracks
```

In view use it as

```
 <?php foreach($most_viewed as $row): ?>// remove $row1 to $row
```

Comment: it would be better to not return from if statement... the method is expected to return something, put the array in an variable and return that.

Comment: Yep return false when no result form query!! Well OP forget to call model function `getFeaturedTracks` @M.I.

Comment: same problem after making these changes.

Comment: Have you change `$data1['most_viewed'] = $this->view_models->getFeaturedTracks();// change mostViewedTracks to getFeaturedTracks
` in controller file!! @AmjadAli

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two mistakes,

```
You should return the `$result` array in your model like,

$results = $query->result();
return $results;
```

And in foreach change `$row1` to `$row` which produces the error. see,

```
<?php foreach($most_viewed as $row): ?>
```

Comment: return $results, u missed the "s"... also instantiate $results as null or empty array and check if is not null or empty before using it in foreach

Comment: same problem after making these changes

Comment: Please check the value of $most_viewed array

Answer (score 0):

Function should like this....

```
function getFeaturedTracks() {
    $results = array();
    $this->load->database();        
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("file");
    $this->db->order_by("views", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(8);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return $results;
}
```