# fetch data from the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-query-builder

i have uploaded a image and related content for it in the database, now im trying to fetch it from their and display it on my webpage, but im getting some errors while fetching it
, so please can any one help me where im going wrong? i don know the concept correctly but just how much i know i have implemented it please help me

this is my Home.php(controller)

```
    <?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Home extends CI_Controller {  

        public function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();

            //load database libray manually
            $this->load->database();

            //load Model
            $this->load->model('Contact_model');

            // load form and url helpers
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            // load form_validation library
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

        public function Latest_news()
        {  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_content', 'First content', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_content', 'Second content', 'required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
            {
                $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH.'uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( $this->upload->do_upload('filename') )
                {
                    //print_r($this->upload->data());die; 
                    $data['first_content'] = $this->input->post('first_content');
                    $data['second_content'] = $this->input->post('second_content');
                    $data['filename'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');  

                    //Transfering data to Model
                    $this->Contact_model->latest_news($data);
                    //Redirecting to success page
                    redirect(site_url('Home/Latest_news'));     
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    print_r($error);die;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                  $this->load->view('Latest_news'); 

            }
        } 


        public function dispdata_latest_news()
        {
        $result['data']=$this->Contact_model->displayrecords_latest_news();
        $this->load->view('display_records',$result);
        }

        ?>
```

Contact_model(model)

```
        <?php
            class Contact_model extends CI_Model 
            {

                function latest_news($data)
                {
                    //saving records
                    $this->db->insert('latest_news', $data); 
                }

                //Display
                function displayrecords_latest_news()
                {
                    //Displaying Records
                    $query=$this->db->query("select first_content from latest_news");
                    return $query->result();
                }

            }

        ?>
```

index.php(view)

```
    <div class="lates">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/4.jpg');?>" class="img-responsive" />

           <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Content</th>

            </tr>
            <?php foreach($query  as $r): ?>
            <tr><?php echo $r->content; ?>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your controller `dispdata_latest_news` should be like this :

```
public function dispdata_latest_news()
{
  $rows = $this->Contact_model->displayrecords_latest_news();
  $result = array('data' => $rows);

  /* OR use it like this 
    $result = ['data' => $rows];
  */

  $this->load->view('display_records',$result);
}
```

Your model `displayrecords_latest_news` should be like this :

```
function displayrecords_latest_news()
{
  $query = $this->db->get("latest_news");
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
      return $query->result();
  }
```

}

*Your view should be like this :*

```
<?php 
   if (! empty($data))
   {
     foreach($data  as $r){ ?>
        <tr><?php echo $r->first_content; ?></tr>
<?php }
   }
   else { ?>
        <tr>no record found</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/index.php

Line Number: 107

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\views\index.php
Line: 107
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 27
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: its pretty simple code pls cross check your code in controller it should be   `$result['data']=$this->Contact_model->displayrecords_latest_news();`

Comment: Just updated my answer copy and use my code and check what u got, see my updated answer

Comment: Sir I'm not getting any errors now but the content which is their in my database is not getting displayed on my web page

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (functions.js:67)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)

Comment: its a js error not related to your php code and content u getting not displayed on your web page  is just beacause ur `$data` is empty

Comment: use `print_r($result);die;` in your controller before the view loading to check what is coming

Comment: sir i just pasted the code print_r($result);die; above $this->load->view('display_records',$result);

Comment: updated `dispdata_latest_news` method see my updated answer

Comment: make sure column name should be correct what u r accessing in your view

Comment: thank you sir what u said i tried and it helped me. i would say its not completely clear answer but around 90% it was correct thank you sir for helping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951168/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-codeigniter

Comment: <table>
      <?php
      if( !empty($results) ) {
       foreach($results as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<h3>'.$row->first_content.'</h3>';
        echo '<p>'.$row->second_content.'</p>';
        echo '</tr>';
       }
      }
      ?>
     </table>

Comment: sir i used this in my view, i have one simple doubt i want to fetch only single row so wht i should for that because, if i use this im getting all the row which is their in the 
database

Comment: instead of `$query->result();` in your modal use `$query->row();` this will fetch only single row

Answer (score 1):

***I have check your all files and codes and i think you have wrong in your view file.***
You have use $r->content. I think where you have get the data in model file the column name is different i.e. first_content.
you have to use like this.

```
<?php     foreach($query  as $r): ?>
            <tr>    <?php echo $r->first_content; ?>
            </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: <?php 
                            if (! empty($data))
                            {
                              foreach($data  as $r){ ?>
                                 <tr><?php echo $r->content; ?></tr>
                         <?php }
                            }
                            else { ?>
                                 <tr>no record found</tr>
                         <?php } ?>

Comment: should i replace this whole part